# Conditional Formatting with greater than & less than parameters

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to highlight values in a column that fall between **1** and **50**.

When I use the formula, `=And(c3:c278>1,c3:c278=<50)` none of the values that fall in between 1 and 50 are highlighted.

When I use the formula, `=c3:c278<50` all values less than 50 including blank cells are highlighted.

What needs to be changed with the first formula so that it will function properly?

I assume that when a cell is blank it is still considered to have a value of 0.

Comment: You need to use `<=` instead of `=<`.

Answer (score 2):

I used :

```
=AND(C$3:C$278>=1,C$3:C$278<=50)
```

and it gave :
[image]

Just dragged the formula down, did not enter it as an array formula.

Comment: how is this a conditional format?

Comment: @wizlog it answered the question "What needs to be changed with the first formula so that it will function properly?" actually asked by the OP.

Comment: I realized your answer actually answered the question while mine provided an alternative approach... I was just expecting to see formatting somewhere.

Comment: I think it is because the OP actually asked two questions in one ... So we both did half!! And, both our answers have uses.

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the cells you want the conditional formatting applied to, then on the Home tab click Conditional Formatting (under styles).

The Rule Type is "Format only cells that contain", then edit the Rule Description. 
Choose Cell Value, Between, and type 1 and 50 in each of the respective boxes.

Lastly, choose the format you want to apply and click OK.

This should give you exactly what you want without messing around with formulas (i.e. it's foolproof). Also, blank cells aren't highlighted.

[image: Picture of what it will look like]

Comment: Well, that worked perfectly. I still have one issue and that is when I set a value of "0" as my lowest value, cells that do not contain a value will also turn color. How do I prevent blank cells from responding?

Comment: Well, that worked perfectly. I still have one issue and that is when I set a value of "0" as my lowest value, cells that do not contain a value will also turn color. How do I prevent blank cells from responding? I realize in my original question I set the parameters between 1 & 50 but since then I determined that there will be times when a value of "0" will be entered and there will be blank cells that are to remain blank (absent of color).

Comment: Maybe make the lower limit -.0000000000000001?